# Error running Tensorflow built from source with XLA enabled and without GPU

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

I built and installed tensorflow from source with XLA enabled and GPU disabled (basically I opted N for everything while configuring via ./config except XLA enabling as Y). There were lot of warnings regrding deprecated syntax while building. but the build was successful.
I am able to import tensorflow and run basic print command in session. But while I try to do some computation (for eg. simple addition) it gives me following error:

**2017-06-28 15:09:22.366052: F tensorflow/compiler/xla/statusor.cc:41] Attempting to fetch value instead of handling error Not found: could not find registered computation placer for platform Executor -- check target linkage
Aborted**

I did a bit of debugging and this error comes just after the call from client/sessions.py:1262 to pywrap_tensorflow:

**tf_session.TF_Run(session, options,
feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
status, run_metadata)**

so I believe it's because it is unable to link to _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so.
Can you please provide any fix to this or is there something am doing wrong here?
This is blocking my further task so any kind of help is appreciated!

Thanks & Regards